# Match results and show text before space

Tags: awk, sed

More sure how to show the results before a match.  I can do a simple grep and show the line that matches 'LLLLL'.  How would I show the header before the return.  Thanks for the help.

Data

```
switch-031
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.1.14 = STRING: "switch-031"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.1.15 = STRING: "switch-032"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.7.28 = STRING: "switch-033"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.9.29 = STRING: "switch-034"

switch-041
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.10035.13 = STRING: "switch-044"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.10035.15 = STRING: "switch-043"

switch-051
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.8.2 = STRING: "switch-053"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.10.1 = STRING: "switch-054"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.1.3 = STRING: "switch-052_LLLLL"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.12.5 = STRING: "switch-055"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.23.1.2.1.1.6.12.6 = STRING: "switch-056"
```

Result

```
switch-051
"switch-052_LLLLL"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk 'NF==1{h=$1} /LLLLL/{print h ORS $NF}' file
switch-051
"switch-052_LLLLL"
```

- `NF==1 { h=$1 }` on header records remember the header `h`
- `/LLLLL/ { print h ORS $NF }` on `LLLLL` records print header `h` and last field `$NF`

Answer (score 2):

another alternative `awk`

```
 awk -v RS= '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
               if($i~/LLLLL/) {print $1; print $i; exit}}' file

switch-051
"switch-052_LLLLL"
```

Answer (score 0):

karakfa's answer is great.

You can use perl as well:

```
$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/ = "" } print "$1\n$2" if /^(\S+).*?("[^"]+LLLLL")/s' file
switch-051
"switch-052_LLLLL"
```